# Compare Two Columns For Matching Values And Align Side By Side

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, datatable

The data I have has two columns whose values should match. Since, there are too many rows I have to do following:

- Load both columns
- Compare `A` and `B` to find matching values
- Stack output of column `A` and `B` into two new columns, such that matching values are side by side and values that don't match are at the end of each column.

Is there a faster way to do this such that it applies of any type of data (integer, float or character) comparison?

**Input Data Table**

```
A   B
1   1
2   3
3   4
4   5
5   6
6   7
7   8
8   9
9   10
10  11
```

**Output Data Table**

```
C   D
1   1
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
10  10
2   11
```

Comment: Can you explain more about your ultimate goal? I don't understand the purpose of the requested output format, and understanding that might help to get to an appropriate solution.

Comment: @JonSpring - There are two columns. I want to match these two column with each other for every row value and then print the output of matched values from each of the columns side by side and not matching values at the end with `NA` to make number of rows same for both columns.

Comment: What have you tried doing so far?

Comment: @ethanpasta - I tried looping through each row from column `A` first and used `which(data$A == data$B)`, and then did same with column `B`. But this is taking too long on the big data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. I might have over-complicated this

```
#copy the object to another dataframe
df1 <- df
#Get matched indices for both the columns
inds1 <- match(df$A, df$B)
inds2 <- match(df$B, df$A)
#Replace value in B column in the same order as A
df1$B <- df$B[inds1]
#Order by column B
df1 <- df1[order(df1$B), ]
#Replace NA in B with unmatched value.
df1$B[is.na(df1$B)] <- df$B[is.na(inds2)]

df1
#    A  B
#1   1  1
#3   3  3
#4   4  4
#5   5  5
#6   6  6
#7   7  7
#8   8  8
#9   9  9
#10 10 10
#2   2 11
```

Comment: .@RonakShah - Thank you. What is `df2`?

Comment: sorry, I was testing something else and it is leftover from that.  It should be `df1`. Corrected.

Comment: .@RonakShah - I tested your code output with [Excel](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e7691007-8c57-409d-9985-80d3c5ccf5c6/how-to-arrange-data-in-one-column-based-on-data-in-other-column-in-excel?forum=exceldev) and it matches.

Comment: Using `fastmatch::fmatch` instead of `match` may speed up your process for a large dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You can find which values match between column `A` and `B`, which gives you the upper part of your desired output. Then add those which have no match. For colum `A` this are those which got `NA` from `match` for column `B` this are those where there is no index for the sequence over column numbers:

```
x  <- data.frame(A=1:10, B=c(1,3:11)) #create your dataset

idx <- match(x$A, x$B)
idxNA  <- is.na(idx)
data.frame(C=c(x$A[!idxNA], x$A[idxNA]), D=c(x$B[idx[!idxNA]], x$B[!seq_along(x$B) %in% idx]))
#    C  D
#1   1  1
#2   3  3
#3   4  4
#4   5  5
#5   6  6
#6   7  7
#7   8  8
#8   9  9
#9  10 10
#10  2 11
```

In case you need a sorted output you have to sort `A` and `B` if this is not already the case.